# FastAPI exceptions raised in middleware are not handled by the custom exception_handlers

Tags: exception, fastapi, middleware, starlette

I want to setup an exception handler that handles all exceptions raised across the whole application. The exception in middleware is raised correctly, but is not handled by the mentioned exception handler.

main.py

```
class NewFastApi(FastAPI):
    def __init__(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> None:
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.container: Optional[Container] = None


def setup_exception_handlers(app: NewFastApi) -> NewFastApi:
    app.add_exception_handler(
        InvalidClientIdError, http400_invalid_client_handler
    )
    app.add_exception_handler(InvalidGrantError, http400_invalid_grant_handler)
    app.add_exception_handler(
        InvalidRedirectUriError, http400_invalid_grant_handler
    )
    app.add_exception_handler(
        UnsupportedGrantTypeError, http400_unsupported_grant_type_handler
    )
    app.add_exception_handler(
        InvalidAuthorizationTokenError, http401_invalid_token_handler
    )
    return app

def get_application(test: bool = False) -> NewFastApi:
    # configure logging
    dictConfig(LOGGING_CONFIG)

    application = NewFastApi()

def setup_di(app: FastAPI) -> None:
    db_engine = prov.provide_db(
        database_url=DB_URL, max_connection_count=DB_MAX_CONNECTION_COUNT
    )

    app.add_middleware(
        middleware_class=AuthorizationMiddleware,
        blacklisted_repo=prov.provide_blacklisted_repo(db_engine),
        # handlers=app.exception_handlers,
    )
    app.add_middleware(
        middleware_class=AccessTokenMiddleware,
        blacklisted_repo=prov.provide_blacklisted_repo(db_engine),
    )
    # Register admin-ui controllers on application start-up.
    admin = ui.CustomAdmin(
        app,
        db_engine,
        templates_dir="templates_admin_ui",
        authentication_backend=ui.AdminAuthController(
            secret_key="1111",
            auth_service=prov.provide_admin_auth_service(
                user_repo=prov.provide_user_repo(db_engine),
                password_service=prov.provide_password_service(),
                jwt_service=prov.provide_jwt_service(),
            ),
        ),
    )
    application.add_middleware(
        CORSMiddleware,
        allow_origins=["*"],
        allow_credentials=True,
        allow_methods=["*"],
        allow_headers=["*"],
    )

    application = setup_exception_handlers(application)
    setup_di(application)

    container = Container()
    container.db()
    application.container = container

    application.include_router(router)
    application.mount(
        "/static",
        StaticFiles(directory="src/presentation/api/templates/static"),
        name="static",
    )

    return application

app = get_application()
```

middleware

```
REQUESTS_WITH_AUTH = [
    {"method": "GET", "path": "/userinfo/"},
    {"method": "GET", "path": "/userinfo/jwt"},
    {"method": "POST", "path": "/userinfo/"},
    {"method": "POST", "path": "/introspection/"},
    {"method": "POST", "path": "/revoke/"},
]


class AuthorizationMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    def __init__(
        self,
        app: Any,
        blacklisted_repo: BlacklistedTokenRepository,
        jwt_service: JWTService = JWTService(),
    ) -> None:
        self.app = app
        self.jwt_service = jwt_service
        self.blacklisted_repo = blacklisted_repo

   async def dispatch_func(
    self, request: Any, call_next: Callable[..., Any]
) -> Any:
    for request_with_auth in REQUESTS_WITH_AUTH:
        if (
            request_with_auth["path"] == request.url.path
            and request_with_auth["method"] == request.method
        ):
            token = request.headers.get("authorization") or request.headers.get(
                "auth-swagger"
            )
            if token is None:
                raise InvalidAuthorizationTokenError
```

http401_invalid_token.py

```
async def http401_invalid_token_handler(
    _: Request, exc: InvalidAuthorizationTokenError
) -> JSONResponse:
    headers = {"Cache-Control": "no-store", "Pragma": "no-cache"}
    content = {
        "error": "invalid_token",
        "error_description": "Incorrect authorization token",
    }
    return JSONResponse(
        content=content, headers=headers, status_code=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED
    )
```

I tried adding separate ExceptionMiddleware, converting the Exception and its handler into dictionary.